# Ошибка в коде делает из обычного бота ВК флудера

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

При получении updates бот начинает слать один и тот же ответ(в соответствии с answ[1]) вплоть до остановки скрипта

Полный код - https://drive.google.com/open?id=12Bnha6V1sL3DObEsm9VLxYJO8PQ5BT-r

Но у меня подозрение, что ошибка кроется в коде с 74 строчки:

```
while True:
    try:
        response = requests.get('https://{0}?act=a_check&key={1}&ts={2}&wait=20&mode=2&version=2'.format(data['server'], data['key'], data['ts'])).json() #Само подключение
        try:
            updates = response['updates'];
        except Exception:
            data = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.getLongPollServer?access_token={0}&v={1}&lp_version=2').format(token, api_version).text
            data = json.loads(data)['response']
            continue
        if updates:
            for result in updates: #Начинаем обрабатывать сообщения
                if result[0] == 4:
                    toho = result[3]
                    torep = result[1]
                    information = ("Applying of a bot in {0}").format(toho)
                    logging.info(information) #Учёт статистики
                    print(information)
                    if (result[3] < 2000000000):
                        userid = result[3]
                    else:
                        userid = result[6]['from']
                    answ = result[5].split(' ')
                    if len(answ) > 1:
                        answ[0] = answ[0].lower()
                        answ[1] = answ[1].lower()
                        deny = "Невозможно выполнить '{0}': Отказано в доступе".format(answ[1])
                        if (answ[0] in names and str(userid) not in commands['blacklist'] and ((answ[1] in commands["standart"]) or (answ[1] in commands["SA"]) or  (answ[1] in commands["premium"]))):
                            statistics["IN_MSG"] = statistics["IN_MSG"] + 1
                            statistics["ALL_MSG"] = statistics["IN_MSG"] + statistics["OUT_MSG"]
                            messages_from_boot = messages_from_boot + 1
                            answ_text = result[5].split(' ')
                            if answ[1] in commands['standart']:
                                threading.Thread(target=evalcmds, args=('lib/STNDRT/'+commands['standart'][answ[1]], toho, torep, answ)).start()
                            if answ[1] in commands['premium']:
                                if str(userid) in commands['PREM_USERS']:
                                    threading.Thread(target=evalcmds, args=('lib/PREM/'+commands['premium'][answ[1]], toho, torep, answ)).start()
                                else:
                                    apisay(deny, toho, torep)
                                    statistics["OUT_MSG"] = statistics["OUT_MSG"] + 1
                            if answ[1] in commands['SA']:
                                if str(userid) in commands['SA_USERS']:
                                    threading.Thread(target=evalcmds,args=('lib/SA/'+commands['SA'][answ[1]], toho, torep, answ)).start()
                                else:
                                    apisay(deny, toho, torep)
                                    statistics["OUT_MSG"] = statistics["OUT_MSG"] + 1
                    else:
                        apisay(bad_answ, toho, torep)
    except KeyboardInterrupt as error:
        print('\nStop signal has been taken. Exiting...')
        logging.info('Called Keyboard Interrupt. Bot is stopped')
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что между запросами бота нет задержек -- я не увидел time.sleep или его аналога. Кст, а зачем вручную запросы посылать? Есть ведь специализированные библиотеки, пример с longpoll: https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/master/examples/longpoll.py

Comment: С time.sleep ничего не меняется.
И я хочу научиться чему-то большему, поэтому решил не юзать библиотеки. Благодаря этому можно лучше вникнуть в API

Comment: Ничего не поменяться просто не может, как вы его использовали? Текущий ваш вопрос скорее всего останется без ответа, потому что: 1) не понятно в чем именно у вас ошибка 2) слишком много кода непонятного назначения -- я бы убрал ненужный код, пока проблема повторяется 3) искать тут 74 строку не будут, к сожалению строки не показываются 4) весь нужный код должен быть в вопросе 5) [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка состоит в том,что запрос к лонгполл-серверу идёт до цикла,представленного в вопросе. Перенос

```
method = "messages.getLongPollServer?"
param = ("access_token={0}&v={1}&lp_version=3").format(token, api_version)
data = requests.get(start + method + param).text #Запрос информации для подключения к лонгполл-серверу
data = json.loads(data)['response']
```

в тело цикла решает проблему